# Installing PyQt5 on Windows

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I am trying to install PyQt5 on windows 7 with Python 3.4.  I already installed SIP, but when I try to run the python configure command for PyQt5 I get the following error:

```
Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
Determining the details of your Qt installation...
C:\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\bin\qmake.exe -spec win32-msvc2010 -o qtdetail.mk qtdetail.pro
nmake -f qtdetail.mk release


Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 12.00.21005.1

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.



    "D:\Applications\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe" -f qtdetail.mk.Release



Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 12.00.21005.1

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.



    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -O2 -MD -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -DNDEBUG -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\include" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\include\QtCore" -I"release" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Forelease\ @C:\Users\AK\AppData\Local\Temp\nmAE97.tmp

qtdetail.cpp

..\..\..\..\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\include\QtCore/qglobal.h(38) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory

NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"D:\Applications\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'

Stop.

NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"D:\Applications\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'

Stop.
```

Comment: Why not using the [binary packages](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5) for windows?

Answer (score 0):

Try executing that same command, but from the "Visual Studio Command Prompt". Its a shell with the corresponding enviroment already setted.
If not, the [prebuilt binary packages](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5) are a simpler way

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run the prebuilt installer. The prebuilt installer at Windows system is an `exe` file ,so you can just click on the next button and you will make it work well.